# List of CATVBA InputObjectTypes?

Tags: vba, catia

For CATIA V5, the following lines of code prompt the user to select a feature, filtered by type.

```
Dim InputObjectType(0) As Variant
InputObjectType(0) = "Point"
selection1.SelectElement2(InputObjectType, "Select a point", true)

etc...
```

I want to filter on Geometrical Sets. **"Geometrical Set", "GeometricalSet", and "GeoSet"** do not work. Is there a list or table of object type names? The v5automation.chm file does not offer any clues.

Comment: "do not work" means what? Error message given?

Comment: Correct. I figured out that the proper input to filter for a geometrical set is "HybridBody". However, I'd like the full list of types in case I need to filter by other types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're checking SO for answers or not - doesn't look like many others have been able to answer your questions to date

If this works for you please mark it as an answer and gain points for yourself as well as myself - and helping future users

I believe you can find a Geometrical set by searching for `"HybridBody"`

**Note: Both Geometric set and Repetition(Points and Planes) are HybridBody**

**Change your lines of code to:**

```
InputObjectType(0) = "HybridBody"
selection1.SelectElement2(InputObjectType, "Select a Geo Set", true)
```

Found [a list of types](https://v5vb.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/check-geometry-types/) - not sure if it's full or not

```
Other
Volume
Surface
Cylinder
Sphere
Cone
Plane
Curve
Circle
Line
Point
Axis System
```

Comment: Thank you very much dbmitch. Since you seem to be familiar with catvba, would you be able to help me with the following issue as well? What object type is returned from selectElement = selection1.Item(1).Value? I'm trying to create a function where the user is prompted to select a feature, and I want to pass on that feature object to further lines of code. I'm not sure what the return type of my function should be. Thank you.

Comment: Create a new question - but make sure you google first and check all documentation - reporting back what you tried - and show relevant code with results from debugging

Comment: It does look like an Object - so it probably depends on what is selected. Best bet is to put a Watch on the line after it gets set - and then expand it to see what the Object properties are (of course that's only if you can't find anything in documentation) - Very basic property would be `.Value`

Comment: If you have for example a search criteria and the result of the search are a lot of elements, it will give the value of the first element in selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic elements list:

[image: Generic types:]

And you can use other filters using the same name used in VBA and not for user interface.

```
HybridBody = API
GeometricalSet = UI
```